# Problem inserting a Persian character between two numbers for save in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, save

I want to save a car plaque in the order below.

Example:

```
12 Persian character 423
```

First, two digits, then a Persian character followed by three digits.

But this is stored in SQL Server:

[image]

Data type for plaque:

[image]

What needs to be done in order I want to save and then read it?

Comment: The data type field is Nvarchar. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the character is in a language read right to left, but the numbers are not. If you use `'423c12'` (obviously  replace the  c with the needed character)) I suspect you'll get the **display** format you are after.

Comment: This is a problem with the alignment of RTL, CENTER, LTR, which means I have checked all these alignments but not yet. update picture post please see again or refresh the page again. @Larnu

Comment: The alignment? Not sure what you mean. If you want every row's character to be the same width you need to use a **fixed width** font in your **presentation** layer, the width of the font has nothing to do with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to save Unicode? Use the N prefix:
INSERT INTO YourTable(yourcolumn)
VALUES (N'yourstring')

**Update**:  Trickery to store the value without getting reversed:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
val nVarChar(25)
)

insert into #tbl select Reverse((Reverse(N'12')+N'ص' + Reverse(N'423'))) 

Select * From #tbl
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score -3):

Values with prefix 'N' to solve your problem.

Comment: It's already storing that way evidenced by the screenshot. OP's "issue" *seems* to be that they expect the 12 to be on the left side of the stored data. If that's the case then this is a RTL/LTR text  issue as Larnu points out above

Comment: I also thought is was just a prefix thing.  I was not aware those characters would reverse the outer numbers until I tried it. So... I updated my answer to try and reverse the reverse. Don't know if what I did is legit though.